# Dictionary Database Size - Which algorithms and strategies make it so light?

Tags: database, algorithm, optimization, wordnet

I am going through the database sizes of open dictionaries like [wordnet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.en_US&hl=en) It has almost `52 MB` of **database** size. But I have seen some offline dictionary applications on `Google Play` like

[1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.en_US&hl=en): http://wordnet.princeton.edu/  [English Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.en_US&hl=en)                                       app which uses Wiktionary Database. I do not know how they are managing to provide an **offline dictionary**  with `15 MB` size only and more than `167000` words?

**What might be the way of keeping words in database?**

Comment: To be clear, are we talking about dictionaries in the classical sense of providing definitions, categorization, etc. or are we talking about dictionaries in the sense of spellchecking?

Comment: These are dictionaries. The link of application I provided is a application for Dictionary.

Comment: What is so strange? Usual compression for English text is about 1/5. So, these 15 MB are about 75MB of text. One million of letters is a usual paper-back book. It is about the volume of Large Oxford Dic. As we know from practice, it CAN contain all English dictionary+thesaurus. And Google dictionary is much weaker than Large Oxford Dic. So, they maybe even don't need to compress at all. And if you have large pieces of text in DB, it doesn't make much additional memory.

Comment: Hi Gangus I am using JSON based DB, so it becomes huge when inserting about 150000 documents, each document containing information for one English word. So data size has become almost 100 MB of size which is very bad for a mobile application. Also, How will I be able to make it to 15 MB?

Answer (score 1):

Wordnet packs quite a punch in small memory footprint.

How? - Here is brief picture:

> words are stored into index files for fast search - index.noun,
>   index.adj, etc.
>
> relation between word and offset in definition file - data.noun, etc
>   is provided.
>
> each of line in definition file corresponds to one definition and
>   relationships between words are marked by a symbol and offset. eg.
>   ! for antonym, @ for kind of, etc.
>
> This makes the whole thing pretty compact.

For more info on this read: `man 5 wndb`.

Regarding size:
52MB = 52000KB

for about ~180K words in Wordnet - each word has 52000K/180K ~ 300bytes.

average about 300 bytes to represent definition + relations - good enough.
e.g. (approx)average for each 4 definition(20 chars), 2 usages(20chars), overhead of relation(10 relations)